# Unable to locate an element in selenium webdriver using name and xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

Am very new to Selenium just learnt few things and trying to automate.Unable to locate an element in Selenium webdriver for the below one:

```
<tbody class="jira-restfultable-create">
   <tr class="jira-restfultable-row jira-restfultable-editrow jira restfultable-focused">
       <td class="jira-restfultable-order">
       <td></td>
       <td><textarea class="ztextarea noresize ztextarea-step" rows="4" name="step">  </textarea>
       </td>
   <td>
```

I have written code like

```
driver.findElement(By.name("step")).sendKeys("step-1");
```

and also tried with

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name = 'ztextarea noresize ztextarea-step']")).sendKeys("step-1");
```

Anyone please help me.

And also please suggest some sites or links to learn more about locators especially xpath. I tried  few but not getting it in depth.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="mozilla">
<head>
<body id="jira" class="aui-layout aui-theme-default ka ajax-issue-search-and-view page-type-navigator navigator-issue-only" data-version="6.2" data-aui-version="5.3.5">
<div id="page">
<header id="header" role="banner">
<fieldset class="parameters hidden dont-default-focus">
<script type="text/javascript">
<nav class="aui-header aui-dropdown2-trigger-group" role="navigation" data-aui-responsive="true">
<div class="aui-header-inner">
<div class="aui-header-primary">
<h1 id="logo" class="aui-header-logo aui-header-logo-custom">
<ul class="aui-nav" style="width: auto;">
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<a id="zephyr_je.topnav.tests" class="aui-nav-link aui-dropdown2-trigger " aria-owns="zephyr_je.topnav.tests-content" aria-haspopup="true" title="Zephyr Test Management and Execution" href="/secure/ZephyrWelcome.jspa">Tests</a>
<div id="zephyr_je.topnav.tests-content" class="aui-dropdown2 aui-style-default">
</li>
<li style="display: none;">
<li id="create-menu">
</ul>
</div>
<div class="aui-header-secondary">
</div>
</nav>
</header>
<section id="content" role="main">
<div class="issue-container" tabindex="-1">
<div id="issue-content" class="issue-edit-form">
<div class="stalker-placeholder issue-header js-stalker" style="visibility: hidden; height: 135px; width: 1349px;"></div>
<header id="stalker" class="issue-header js-stalker detached" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
<div class="issue-body-content">
<div class="aui-group issue-body">
<div class="aui-item issue-main-column">
<div id="details-module" class="module toggle-wrap">
<div id="descriptionmodule" class="module toggle-wrap">
<div id="view_issue_steps_section" class="module toggle-wrap">
<div id="view_issue_steps_section_heading" class="mod-header">
<div class="mod-content">
<div id="project-config-panel-versions" class="project-config-panel">
<form id="project-config-versions-add" class="aui" action="#">
<table id="project-config-steps-table" class="aui jira-restfultable jira-restfultable-allowhover">
<thead>
<tbody class="ui-sortable">
<tbody class="jira-restfultable-create">
<tr class="jira-restfultable-row jira-restfultable-editrow jira-restfultable-focused">
<td class="jira-restfultable-order">
<td></td>
<td style="height: 81px;">
<textarea class="ztextarea noresize ztextarea-step" rows="4" name="step" style="height: 72px;"></textarea>
</td>
<td style="height: 81px;">
<td style="height: 81px;">
<td class="jira-restfultable-operations">
<div class="restfultable-operations-wrapper">
<input class="aui-button" type="submit" value="Add" accesskey="s">
</div>
</td>
<td class="jira-restfultable-throbber"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
<div id="project-config-error-console"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="view_issue_execution_section" class="module toggle-wrap">
<div id="view_issue_execution_section_heading" class="mod-header">
<div class="mod-content">
</div>
<div id="activitymodule" class="module toggle-wrap">
<div id="addcomment" class="module">
<div class="mod-content">
<div class="mod-footer">
</div>
</div>
<div id="viewissuesidebar" class="aui-item issue-side-column">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<fieldset class="hidden parameters">
<div id="systemFiltersJson" style="display:none;">[{"id":-1,"name":"My Open Issues","jql":"assignee = currentUser() AND resolution = Unresolved ORDER BY updatedDate DESC","isSystem":true,"sharePermissions":[],"requiresLogin":true},{"id":-2,"name":"Reported by Me","jql":"reporter = currentUser() ORDER BY createdDate DESC","isSystem":true,"sharePermissions":[],"requiresLogin":true},{"id":-3,"name":"Recently Viewed","jql":"issuekey in issueHistory() ORDER BY lastViewed DESC","isSystem":true,"sharePermissions":[],"requiresLogin":false},{"id":-4,"name":"All Issues","jql":"ORDER BY createdDate DESC","isSystem":true,"sharePermissions":[],"requiresLogin":false}]</div>
<div id="inline-dialog-c14577633211060" class="aui-inline-dialog aui-help-tip" style="top: 116px; right: 10px; display: none;">
</section>
<footer id="footer" role="contentinfo">
</div>
<div id="fancybox-tmp"></div>
<div id="fancybox-loading">
<div id="fancybox-overlay"></div>
<div id="fancybox-wrap">
<div id="edit-issue-dialog" class="jira-dialog box-shadow" style="display: none;">
<div id="create-subtask-dialog" class="jira-dialog box-shadow" style="display: none;">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: name is 'step' and what you are giving is class name. Please give 'step' as a name it'll get element.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake ,i have tried with 'step' also but its not working. Getting error as org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"step"}

Comment: Check do you have iframe or not?

Comment: Please post html of whole document. may be i can help you further.

Comment: posted the whole html doc.Plz help me

Comment: your html is not in proper sequence. Even some tag don't have closing tag. Header started  but not ended like this so many tag not closed and proper form. Please provide updated and correct html. I tried but due to not correct html i couldn't get what you want. Waiting for proper html. Then i can provide answer of your question. Please update question. Wating....

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad . Posted whole document,have a look on it

Comment: Dear there is issue in your html. you didn't close script tag that's why you are facing this issue. you just close script tag after opening or remove it. and try code which i have posted in answer. it will work fine. i have tested and working fine but after closing script tag. or remove script tag if you don't need it. if need it then close and do other works. if still you face any issue then let me know. my answer is working fine i have tested. specially CSS Selector. Waiting for your reply. Thanks.

Comment: The document is html, not an xml, so html is ok even when there is no closing tag.

Comment: @Rao yes html is ok. But i have mention you just copy HTML form question and past it in notepad save as HTML open in browser and check. then close script tag and save changes and then check hope so you'll get what is my point of comments and **What is difference of closing and opening tag properly in HTML**

Answer (score 0):

try following code.

```
//Get by Name
driver.findElement(By.name("step")).sendKeys("step-1");
// Get by Tag Name
driver.findElement(By.tagName("textarea")).sendKeys("step-1");
//Get element using css selector
WebElement textArea= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea[name='step']"));
```

Comment: @Harish according to me and my thinking there is issue in HTML what you have posted here and what you have at your end. I don't think so any other issue will be there.